# Newbie: cannot compile successfully with my first c++ demo

Tags: c++

all, I am an absoluty newbie of c/c++. When I compile my main.cpp in ubuntu command line: **g++  main.cpp**, coming with following error:

> main.cpp:(.text+0xa8)：for‘mesh(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator >)’undefined reference
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

All my codes are:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "mesh.h" 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout<< argc << std::endl;  
  argv[0] = "main"  argv[1] = "buffer.obj"
  std::cout<< argv[1] << std::endl;
  std::string filename = "map.obj";
  mesh(filename);
 
  return 0;
}
```

mesh.h

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void mesh(std::string filename);
```

mesh.cpp

```
#include "mesh.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void mesh(std::string filename){
   
  std::cout << filename << std::endl;
  
}
```

Comment: do `g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp mesh.cpp`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, while comes with g++: error: Wextra: No such file or directory

Comment: The compiler (in fact: the linker) complains about the missing defintion of the function mesh. How should he know that it can be found in the file mesh.cpp if you do not tell it to him.

Comment: @xiaoxingzeng I guess you forgot the dash before `Wextra`. Use `-Wextra`

Comment: Yes, I missing the dash in command line. Thanks very much!